# How to make element that has changed from display:none to display:block available in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am trying to apply some javaScript on an element that initially has a display:none attribute. Example:

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('container').style.display='block';">

<div style="display:none;" id="container">
<input type="text" name="somename" id="somename" onclick="applySomeJsToTextField();">
</div>

function applySomeJsToTextField() {
//js code here
}
```

Since the element is not visible to the DOM of loaded as or within a display:none element, how can I change this?

Thanks

Comment: Edit: I found a way around with document.createElement but is there a more simple or straightforward way?

Comment: What causes you to believe that the element is not in the DOM? It should be.

Comment: Turns out I was under the wrong impression... damn :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the element has the `display` property set to something *means* that the element is in the DOM.

You can apply some JS to hidden elements, they're still elements loaded in the DOM.

Comment: I always was under the impression that elements with display:none were not visible to the DOM. What a bugger! But I do remember having such an issue previously. I guess there was something else going on and I have misunderstood the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter, whether it is visible or not. It is accessible in either case

Answer (score 0):

a small function to toggle visibility might be:

```
functionToggleDiv()
{
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.style.display = (container.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');
}
```

However, if this code doesn't work for you, then maybe the dom isn't fully loaded, insert the JS after the elements you're interacting with, or look into other methods (`window.onload` etc) to get around this.

Just a thought: but if all the style attribute contains is the `display:none;` but, you might care to try: `document.getElementById('container').removeAttribute('style');`. It's not the way I'd advise, though but neither is creating a new Element, which you said to be doing in your comment.